# Is there any possibility to get Device Farm Logcat through AWS Device Farm CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-device-farm

Is there any possibility to get Device Farm Logcat through AWS Device Farm CLI ?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the logcat file after the job has finished using [the `list-artifacts` command](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/devicefarm/list-artifacts.html). Use the Run ARN and `type=LOG` to get a list of links to the logcat files. You can then use a utility like `curl` to download the files.

Comment: Can we get iOS Console Log also ?